# Email Success/Rejection Conditions

Tags: json, jpa, xml-parsing, email-attachments, email-validation

I will be getting emails from the supplier in the `.xml and .pdf formats`, I have to read all the emails and store into oracle `db` through `JPA`, email conditions success and rejection mails are sent back with:

```
Rejection mails - zip, multiple attachments, without attachment
success emails - from json response
```

---

```
{
    "status": 202,
    "message": "success",
    "timestamp": 1682395068503,
    "data": {
        "taxId": "AAA120730823",
        "legalName": "ASESORES Y ADMINISTRADORES AGRICOLAS, S. DE R.L. DE C.V.",
        "additionalData": {
            "queryDate": "2023-04-24T21:57:48",
            "found": "Si",
            "statusTaxIds": [
                {
                    
            ]
        }
    },
    "success": true
}
```

fetch found : based on it send success message with attachments back
How can I do this please help me, email rejections and success..

```
Java, springboot, jpa hibernate
```

Tried to read email attachments and saved in `Oracle Database` in columns and entire email as blob in one of the column, Now email `success and rejection` conditions needs to be added.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Which part of your problem are you having trouble with?